# CMAKE linking to system library

Tags: c++, c, cmake

We would like to build a shared library with `CMAKE` system. It's something like:

```
lib/
  CMakeLists.txt
  src/
    CMakeLists.txt
    module/
      CMakeLists.txt
      module1.c
    foo.c
```

`module1.c` needs some standard shared library like `librt`. We have

```
add_library(module module1.c)
target_link_libraries(module rt)
```

in the `module/` sub-directory. But still getting errors that stuff from `librt` is not known.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually what you are doing should work. If the compiler cannot find the library it may simply not be in the standard library paths. You can use the following help to specify different `link_directories` (`-L/some/path` parameter to the compiler).

```
cmake --help-command link_directories
```

Another useful thing you can do while debugging CMake builds is print out the commands it runs the compiler with:

```
make VERBOSE=1
```

You can then take the commands and manually tailor them to work. After that it is a matter of modifying `CMAKE_C_FLAGS`/`include_directories`/`link_directories`

Answer (score 7):

If librt is linked with -lrt, then in CMake you can link it in this way:

```
target_link_libraries(module -lrt)
```

Comment: Not a good idea according to http://voices.canonical.com/jussi.pakkanen/2013/03/26/a-list-of-common-cmake-antipatterns/

Comment: Not a good idea according to a site that no longer exists. Not very helpful.

Comment: The above site is archived here: https://web.archive.org/web/20190722182127/http://voices.canonical.com/jussi.pakkanen/2013/03/26/a-list-of-common-cmake-antipatterns/